# How can i set entire row as hyperlink in SSRS report?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have created SSRS report which has multiple column like date, time , location, note fields & group by meeting-name.

On date field, i have created hyperlink to open another report of document related to particular meeting.

Now i want to set hyperlink on entire row in SSRS report to open another report.

Comment: In SSRS, only labels have the navigate to or jump to property. You will have to kludge this and use JavaScript on the client or scale back you requirements.

Comment: Can you just repeat the hyperlink on each field?

Comment: @SMM, correct we can repeat the hyperlink on each field, but looking fragment and not work as entire row.

Comment: @RossBush i am not sure about javascript will be work on report viewer content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible using the built in SSRS controls to have a row click take you to another report, however, there are hacks. Unless you want to spend a lot of time getting things right, I would suggest just scaling back your requirements on this ;)

**Modify ReportingServices.js**

**This is a complete hack**. This file resides in the Reporting Services installation folder on the server and is loaded by the ReportViewer control to render server side reports. You could add some semantics there to customize and extend functionality in your reports. [Here](https://direit.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/ssrs-use-custom-javascript-to-call-a-report-in-a-new-tabwindow/) is a little more detail and an example of this method.

**Modify PageThatContainReportViewer.aspx**

You can add Javascript code to the page that contains the report viewer. Since JavaScript will call up for functions then js you place in your root page will be reachable by your report. Also, you can interact with the report contents once the report is rendered in the viewer, **again, a complete hack**.

Comment: Hi Ross. Out of curiosity, do you know if that would work with SharePoint integration? I'm not saying I'm going to try it but we have had the odd thing come up where we have said "what if...".

Comment: I would suggest either placing a View More... button or making every label a hyperlink. It is an undocumented and possibly error prone path kludging this client side.